# I'm doing a machine learning project using MNIST data set with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm getting this error for some reason and I have no idea why? Any help is appreciated. I'm doing MNIST handwritten digit recognition on jupyter notebook. The x_train array is a (70000,784) array.

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6700/1983129579.py in <module>
      1 shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(6000)
----> 2 x_train, y_train = x_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3459             if is_iterator(key):
   3460                 key = list(key)
-> 3461             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3462 
   3463         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([4112, 3293,  403, 2579,  942,  987, 3778, 3831, 3053, 3412,\n            ...\n             642, 2789, 3410, 3946, 5883, 3439, 2029, 2776, 4626,  497],\n           dtype='int64', length=6000)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Add error trace and minimal reproducible code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 4):

If x_train and y_train are DataFrames and you want the result to be a DataFrame you can use use:

```
x_train = x_train.iloc[shuffle_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in a wrong way, it should be like this

```
x_train = np.random.permutation(x_train)
y_train = np.random.permutation(y_train)
```

You can also refer here for examples
[np.random.permutation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html)

Comment: This is what I was doing earlier:
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(6000)
x_train, y_train = x_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]
Is it still wrong?

Comment: I guess you are trying to shuffle the data, right? What is happening with this one is that you are trying to index a 2D numpy array with a 1D list that's why the error came up.